# Shopware 5 call custom function in template file

Tags: shopware5

I am using Shopware 5.6.1 version. I have created custom plugin.
I want to call custom function in template file as below :-

\Resources\views\frontend\checkout\confirm.tpl

```
{extends file="parent:frontend/checkout/confirm.tpl"}
{block name='frontend_index_content'}
    {Here I wanted to add custom function result}
    {$smarty.block.parent}
{/block}
```

Can anyone please confirm how can I achive the same.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to add a Smarty plugin.
Depending on whether you use a theme or plugin to extend, there are two ways:

1. Theme: *themes/Frontend/ThemeName/_private/smarty/function.**example**.php*
   Replace example with the actual function name you want to call in he template.
2. Plugin:

```
<?php
namespace PluginName\Components\CompilerPass;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
/**
 * Class AddTemplatePluginDirCompilerPass
 */
class AddTemplatePluginDirCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $template = $container->getDefinition('template');
        $template->addMethodCall('addPluginsDir', ['directory/name']);
    }
}
```

Register CompilerPass class in build method in plugin boostrap class:

```
/**
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 */
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->addCompilerPass(new AddTemplatePluginDirCompilerPass());
}
```

credits and also see the shopware 5 developer documentation
https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/smarty/#register-custom-smarty-plugins